# Hanami framework doesn't work with many to many through?

Tags: ruby, hanami

I used rich many to many...

```
class OwnerRepository < Hanami::Repository
 
    associations do 
        has_one :avator
        has_many :oneships#It's for join table..
        has_many :avators,through: :oneships
    end


    def find_with_avator(id)
        aggregate(:avator).where(id: id).map_to(Owner).one
    end

    def find_with_avators(id)
        aggregate(:avators).where(id: id).map_to(Owner).one
        #This found one avator but should be found two???
    end

end
```

I create two owners and two avator for each owner,And every owner has two avators with through oneship.
But when i want to find avators with given owner_id,Give me one result.
In other side Avator Repository works fine..
Why?

Comment: That's because you are using `#one`.

Comment: I write just like docs

Comment: Why from AvatorRepository works fine?

Comment: I assume that `AvatarRepository` declares a `belongs_to` association with `OwnerRepository`. This kind of association is designed to return one record, that's why `#one` works.